# How would I run my Shopify app's install code in conjunction with the user accepting the installation?

Tags: node.js, shopify

I'm building my first Shopify App using Node.js, and I cannot figure out how to run my install script once the user accepts the app via Shopify's install portal. It's a private app at the moment and cannot take advantage of Shopify's Embedded App API.

Authorization and getting a token has been no problem, and I'm able to make my API requests just fine. However, I want to add metafields to products and orders as soon as the app is installed. I can't seem to find any resources on this problem, or am simply blind to it.

Is there a way to designate my own redirect once the user accepts the install? Or some other workaround that I'm just not seeing?

And while on this topic, would the same solution be able to apply to when a user uninstalls the app (so I can remove the changes my app made)?

Thanks in advance. I also should note that I'm a Node.js novice.

Manually calling a separate route works. However, I want it to run automatically.

```
router.get('/install', function (req, res, next) {
    var shop = req.query.shop;
    var appId = process.env.appId;

    var appSecret = process.env.appSecret;
    var appScope = process.env.appScope;
    var appDomain = process.env.appDomain;

    //build the url
    var installUrl = `https://${shop}/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=${appId}&scope=${appScope}&redirect_uri=https://${appDomain}/shopify/auth`;

    res.redirect(installUrl);
    // User is redirected to Shopify App install portal and accepts
    // Run setup code here
});
```

I want the install process to be seamless, but at the moment an extra manual step is necessary to complete the install.

Answer (score 0):

**Add metafields to products and order**
Yes you can add metafields by calling the metafields API. More information - [Link](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/metafield)

**Designate custom redirect once the user accepts the install**
You are already passing the redirect URL during the installation phase by a parameter `redirect_uri`. This is the URL where the user will be redirected on a successful installation. You would need to whitelist the URL in your App settings.

**When a user uninstalls the app remove the changes made by App**
You will get a webhook notification if you have set up the same informing you about the App uninstall. So, you can do changes you want on your side. Eg - Deleting customer data, merchant data etc. However, if you have edited any liquid file or you have added any file, the same won't be removed and you won't be able to to access it as your access token gets invalidated. Any webhooks, onload scripts you would have added gets removed though.